# How to fix bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

The bootstrap carousel is not functioning properly. It just displays one image but it is not changing.

The code for carousel was copy and pasted directly from bootstrap's documentation and I just changed the image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-CN">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Carousel</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="/static/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="carouselExampleSlideOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block" src="/static/images/Ditto.png" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block" src="/static/images/Ditto.png" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block" src="/static/images/Ditto.png" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@1.12.4/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide a link from the place where you found this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bootstrap styles import seems to be wrong, replace it with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and replace your script codes with the following:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and it should do the trick!
You can refer to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Thanks! The three images did become one after I added the line. However, they are not moving as they should be, can you tell me why?

Comment: Yes @LanceZhang, replace your scripts as well with the ones in the page I've attached above, I've edited the answer above